# Supported Interfaces: REST SOAP

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to create a simple webmap and I want to add the layers of a map that I published to the GIS server. But the rest URL from the published map do not display these layers. Anyone know what the problem is?

[image]

I noticed that I was missing the section "Supported Interfaces:   REST   SOAP   WMS" as you see from the picture, could that be the reason?

I am very new to this.

Below is a snipped of code that I used to test the rest url.

```
  require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",

  ], function (
    Map, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer) {

    map = new Map("mapDiv", {
    basemap: "topo",

      sliderOrientation : "horizontal"
    });


    var dynamicMapServiceLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("rest url link");

    map.addLayer(dynamicMapServiceLayer);
```

Comment: if you click on the "export map" link at the bottom of the page, does it give you an image of the map?
what you could also do is to examine the link the webmap is generating: click on the developer tools in your browser (ctrl+shift+i), click on the network analysis tab and find the url which supposed to load the map (I guess it starts with  "export?.."). Copy that link in a new browser tab and check if it works. Ideally it would tell you what the problem is.